# Creating a book from HTML page (MS Word type pages)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have bunch of topics inserted in database, now I want to print them and make a book with Index page specifying page number of each topic, as there are 300 topics I am avoiding it do manually.

So what should I do to have a word type functionality so that I can have divs as pages and extra (overflown data) is broken to next page like in google docs as live in browser example and MS Word.

I am using php language to fetch and output data from database.

Comment: I am sorry to see a down rating but I dont even know how to define my problem and what words should I use in google as even it is not helping me out.

Comment: This is more of a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ than here... This site is more for help with already written code I wrote that isn't working, than to tell you how to program or design a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use web browsers for printing.  Browsers are notoriously bad at printing, especially if you want consistent results across different browsers.

Generate PDF files or even Word docs.

Here's the [php reference for creating and editing PDF files](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php).

As an aside, also don't use PDF for online viewing.  PDFs are for printing, HTML is for viewing.

Comment: The reason I am stuck with browser is because of formatting, initially it was planned only to be seen in browser so all the topics were save with html formatting(<li>, <p>, <br>, <hr>) in database

Comment: Whoops!  Presentation layer code in the data layer is a recipe for problems down the road.  Still, all is not lost.  Check out some of the php HTML to PDF converters, such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).  Also, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how will I be able to create a Index page and set page numbers?